# How do you find the equation of motion in the absence of damping (x(complementary) and x(particular) solved)?

Tags: calculus, algebra-precalculus, ordinary-differential-equations

Let $x(0) = 0$, $x'(0) = 0$, and take a particular solution
$x_p = e^{-2t}(\frac{1}{2}\cos(4t) - 2\sin (4t))$ and homogeneous solution
$x_c = c_1 e^{8t} + c_2 e^{8t}$.

1. So I put those two together to find the equation of motion:
   $$x = c_1 e^{8t} + c_2 e^{8t} + e^{-2t}(\frac{1}{2}\cos (4t) - 2 \sin (4t))$$
2. So all I need to do is find $c_1$ and $c_2$ now by plugging in the initial values,
   $$x(0) = c_1 + c_2 + \frac{1}{2} = 0, \; c_1 + c_2 = -\frac{1}{2}.$$

Now how am I supposed to find $c_1$ or $c_2$ from this?

1. $x'(0) = 8c_1 + 8c_2 - 9 = 0$

Same for this step, how can I find the unknown constants? I cannot eliminate one of the two...

The answer is $$x = -\frac{1}{2}\cos (4t) + \frac{9}{4} \sin(4t) + \frac{1}{2}e^{-2t} \cos (4t) - 2e^{-2t}\sin (4t).$$

Comment: Are you sure you wrote $x_c$ correctly? Did you mean for one of those to be $-8t$?

Comment: Maybe you can just provide the original ODE.

Comment: @Amzoti (1/16)x'' + 32x = 68*e^(-2t)*cos(4t)

Comment: Are you sure you wrote that correctly?  (1/16)x'' + 32x = 68*e^(-2t)*cos(4t). Something is wrong with this DEQ and/or the initial values.

Comment: Have you abandoned this post?

Answer (score 1):

Probably the right equation is $$2x''+32x=68\,e^{-2t} \cos {4t}$$Start from this and you will find $c_1$ and $c_2$ with no problems.